# How do I include extern functions from dependency crates?

Tags: rust, ffi

I had some `extern "C"` functions in my Rust library; then I decided to split the library up into a bunch of crates and make one workspace crate that just re-exports everything from its members. However, now that I have done this, the symbols for these `extern "C"` functions are missing from the generated `.so` file. How can I fix this?

I tried re-exporting the `extern "C"` functions individually; this did not work. I also tried setting `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` on the crate containing the functions, and this didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2771), the behaviour I'm seeing is a bug and there doesn't seem to be any known solution besides wrapping the functions that I want to re-export.